# fetch data every 10 minutes in ionic 3 android

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

How to fetch data every 10 minutes in ionic 3 my code is below here..

```
getStudentStatus() {
let item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('username'))
this.auth.getStudentData(item.username).then(
  data => {
    this.studentList = data;
  }
)
```

}

Thank's in advance

Comment: does `auth` return a promise? why not use observable?

Comment: ok i'll try.. thank's mike @MikeTung

Comment: wanna give me best answer now? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fetch data every 10 mins you can use rxjs to help you here with an Observable that polls every 10secs.

```
getStudentStatus() {
let item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('username'))
let poll$ = Observable.interval(10000);

poll$.subscribe(() => this.auth.getStudentData(your logic));
)
```

Comment: is automatic run in background app? @MikeTung

Comment: @BrianYudhanto it'll keep running so long as your component or whatever isn't destroyed. The subscription continues until you say stop. Make sure to implement `unsubscribe()` in `ngOnDestroy` to prevent leaks.

Comment: Ok mike this is the best answer thank you. haha.. @MikeTung

Comment: np just lemme know if you got more questions ;)