# How to develop functionality to limit application usage - Ionic 3

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am developing an application for a client and I would like a usage timeout. For example, the user installs the app and after 3 hours it can no longer use. What would be the best way to do this?

I could do it in the most basic way, recording a time flag to check every time the app loads, but how do **I prevent the user from uninstalling and reinstalling the app and can use it again?**

**Can I record a global variable on Android?**

Comment: phone storage will be deleted when he uninstall the app
i think you should save it on a server.

Comment: @George Maybe it's the best option.

Comment: AFAIK you can't store it on the mobile because he can clear data or uninstall or whatever.
you have to store it someone externally. so if you are already using a database and connecting via api then it is easy, link that number with the device id.

Comment: if you are not then check cloud solutions that offers data storage, i believe firebase have something like that.
let me know if you need more info regarding both ways.

Comment: @George I really think it's the best option. When I read your suggestion I immediately thought, "but the user can turn off Wi-Fi or data connection." But I remembered that I can force the user to connect one of the two. That is, I only allow the user to use the app if it connects the Wi-Fi and/or data connection. Thank you! Note: If I elaborate a response with this suggestion I will mark it as an answer. I think it will be useful for someone else in the future.

Comment: yes that sound great,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After user first time installs the app you can get unique UUID for that device using for example [Ionic Native Device plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device/) and send it to your database along with timestamp.

```
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';

constructor(private device: Device) { }

...

console.log('Device UUID is: ' + this.device.uuid);
```

After that, it's enough [at some time intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255907/fetch-data-every-10-minutes-in-ionic-3-android) or every time an API is called, compare that time in the database with current time and if more than three hours have passed prohibit calling all APIs from device with that UUID. The application will, in that case, become unusable.

Of course, you can always allow a particular user (UUID) to use it for a long time.